# Does IBKR require a minimum account balance in order to trade with your own cash (without margin account)?

Tags: stocks, brokerage, interactive-brokers

I don't have a margin account. I have a normal cash account and I have about 700 EUR in it. When I place a limit order to buy, I get this error message:

[image]

As mentioned, I don't have a margin account. ***On their website, they specify that they don't require an account minimum:*** https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/accounts/required_minimums.php. I have an individual client account with IBKR PRO. I live in Germany if this is necessary info.

I don't user margin. I don't short. I just want to buy long on my individual client cash account. ***Why isn't this working?***

[image]

Comment: What did their customer support tell you?

Comment: They didn't respond. I'm trying again tmrw. or on Monday in case they don't respond tomorrow either.

Comment: Is all the cash settled?

Comment: Yes, the cash is settled.